# I would like to record both music and a pdf on a cd (music as .cda)

Tags: audio, pdf

I as involved in the production of a cantata in the 1960s and have at last found a vinyl copy of the rehersal and presentation tracks. Having converted the vinyl to mp3 and created a pdf from the score I wold like to transfer them to a single CD. I can create a data disk, that's no problem but I would like to be able to play the music on a standard CD player, and have the pdf available to be read and/or printed via a computer

Comment: read this: http://www.maximumpc.com/article/How-To--Burn-Music-and-Data-on-the-Same-Disc

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 choices here.

An Audio CD, which, as the title suggests only supports audio, but it will work in all audio players, or a Mixed-mode CD, which can both data and audio tracks, where the first track is for data.

All recent audio cd players will automatically skip the first track, but not all do this. At least 10 years ago, this was still the case. The question becomes how compatible you want this to be. If this is going to be for a broad audience and compatibility is essential, you should be looking into providing the booklet by a different means, and use Audio CD. Otherwise a Mixed-mode CD will do.

Most recording software will allow you to do this. Usually they call it Mixed mode CD.

A free tool that can do this is: InfraRecorder, which has a portable version located at portablefreeware.com